# Why I do not get the message from php contact form?

Tags: php, email, contact-form

I'm tryng to test contactForm but I do not get the message. Can you help me?
I get this form from internet. In "my@email.com" I know I must replace with real email addres, just now for this post.

This is my php:

```
   <?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "my@email.com";
$email_subject = "Your email subject line";

function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||        
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required    
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be  valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";   
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
sleep(2);
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=\"0;              url=http://localhost/eni92/eni92.php\">";
?>

<?php
 }
?>
```

And my form:

```
 <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-custom contactForm" data-toggle="modal">Отворете Формата за Връзка с Нас</a>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Форма за връзка с нас</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <form class="form-horizontal" name="commentform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="first_name">Име</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" required="" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Име"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="last_name">Фамилия</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Фамилия"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="email">Email Адрес</label>
            <div class="col-md-6 input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                <input type="email" required class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Адрес"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="comment">Въпрос или Коментар</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <textarea rows="6" required class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Напишете Вашия въпрос или коментар тук"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-custom pull-right">Изпрати</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div><!-- End of Modal body -->
    </div><!-- End of Modal content -->
    </div><!-- End of Modal dialog -->
</div><!-- End of Modal -->
    <!--contact us form edn-->
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm new in php so i need some help and cant understant the othe question like mine. Sorry

Comment: if this "server" is an actual webhost, it likely has sendmail etc configured and it's a problem with your code. BUT If this "server" is on your desktop, it likely isn't configured to send to remote domains, so instead try sending to "localuser@localhost"  and see if that works

Comment: it.s on localhost. Ok I will try. Thank you